# App to Cast videoconference (zoom, skype, telegram)

Tags: android, chromecast, android-tv, video-conferencing, zoom-sdk

Lets imagine i want to build some app for videoconferences or videomeeting that is chromecast-compatible.
So i can use my android device to connect meeting, after that i just click something like "cast to device" and get audio and video on my TV.

Also i noticed that skype, zoom, discord and all apps like this has not bulid-in chromecast support. So maybe it is impossible?
I tried to find something about that but but found nothing useful. I found zoom sdk, and chromecasst sdk, but not seen what actually i shoud cast. As i understood chromecast can send only media-content to reciever, but zoom sdk not actually provide some media-like links for conversation(videoconference).

So i want to know what are  my steps to build my own chromecast-compatible meeting app and what may i want to use to develop app like that?
Or maybe someone know how can i use Zoom sdk to achive what i want?

Answer (score 0):

When a sender device connects to a Chromecast, it has a limited set of "[commands](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.messages#.MessageType)" it can send to the device.

There is no immediate way to send data other than those messages from the sender to the device - there is a 'custom' message, but that too only includes stringified JSON

The way this would have to work is too set up a stream of the screen/app you want to display via Chromecast and send a `LOAD` message to the Chromecast which will connect back to the sender (or a third party server where the video can be streamed from) and play it.

I'm not too confident this is going to work as intended though - there will be a significant delay between the sender and the Chromecast, and since the Chromecast has no mic, you will also have to use the mic of the sender and deal with the acoustic feedback.

Comment: Looks like you suggest to simply do screen mirroring. It's not what i want. I want somethig like, you know, chromecast games.

Comment: Look at the documentation. A Chromecast game would leverage the 'custom' message to send stringified JSON to a custom receiver app. That translates those into input for the JS gaming logic. There is no other "pushed" data transfer available from the sender to the chromecast. Everything else is pulled by the chromecast.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.messages#.MessageType